# Multitenancy to my existing angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, apache, rest, nginx, web

I have a requirement to implement multitenancy to my existing angularjs app.

I ll be having multiple clients and multiple clients will be having many users, each client might have own customization. How to control this using angularJS?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a vast subject... but here are some leads :

- Once user has successfully logged in, keep its tenant in localStorage or a cookie.
- Pass tenant to backend API calls, in a custom header like `X-Tenant` or API prefix like `/tenantxx`
- Prefix stylesheets base path :`/tenantxx/styles.css`

Comment: Hello Stej4n. Thank you for your help.

So the biggest difficulty is that I do not have login according to the client, I wanted something like so:
(www.client1.project.com.br)
(www.client2.project.com.br)

And according to the url I would know which database to target.
In theory the following happens, client1 (api REST: 187.14.4.4), client2 (api REST: 189.10.12.4).

Because the current architecture each client has q its database.